# Prohibit any interaction with system for user

Tags: centos, files, permissions, users

I'm looking for a way to isolate user from system completely and only allow the user to log-in to system and interact with opened programs.

One way I could achieve this is by stripping all permissions for every individual folder and/or file.

Goal of mine is to have user log-in to my system, and give the user access to only one Java executable, which the user can then start and interact.

Are there any better way of doing this?

Thank you

Comment: It sounds like you want to run your Java executable as [Kiosk sofware](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kiosk_software) - see for example [XGUEST: KIOSK MODE](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/selinux_users_and_administrators_guide/sect-security-enhanced_linux-confining_users-xguest_kiosk_mode)

Comment: @steeldriver this seems what I need. My need is to make Java file only exectuable, but not readable/writable. Also, whenever software updates, there is a new Java file in place of another, so it would be great if I could chmod files once and still have a working solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably want to set these users default shell to `/bin/rbash` -- restricted bash (`bash -r`). See `man rbash`. This can be done is done with the command `chsh -s /bin/rbash {USER}`.

To prevent them from executing other commands than the one you want, set their PATH variable environment to only the folder containing the executable you want them to run in their `~/.bash_profile`:

```
export PATH="$HOME/bin"
```

---

Edit:

At this point, it is still possible for an attacker to break out of rbash. Actually, `ssh` allows running remote commands. They can still do something like `ssh ... cp /bin/bash bin`, to add bash to the set of commands they can run. The problem is that when run directly from ssh, it seems bash (or rbash) does not read `.bash_profile`, nor `.profile`, nor `/etc/profile`.

The link (2) proposes solutions to this problem. `man sshd_config` describes all the options which can be set in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`. Apparently, the script `~/.ssh/rc` (as well as `/etc/sshrc` see link (4)) is run when we need it to be - whenever a user ssh some command. But I haven't tested.

At this point, it may or may not still be possible to break from rbash using `scp`.

Also, you'll need to disable SFTP in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`. This is done by commenting the line:

```
Subsystem sftp       /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server
```

Links:

- (0) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/402615/how-to-restrict-ssh-users-to-a-predefined-set-of-commands-after-login
- (1) https://serverfault.com/questions/28858/is-it-possible-to-prevent-scp-while-still-allowing-ssh-access
- (2) https://serverfault.com/questions/133242/disabling-all-commands-over-ssh
- (3) https://access.redhat.com/solutions/65822
- (4) https://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/networking_2ndEd/ssh/ch08_04.htm

Comment: Very interesting, thanks. Do you think I could write a bash script that would execute a Java program and only allow user to use that one command for newly created script? I would like to use that in hopes to prohibit user from writing/viewing Java file's source code and move its location for example.

Comment: That was a good answer.